# How do I change the language for 3rd party applications in Windows?

Tags: windows, language

How do I change the default language for 3rd party application in Windows like Dropbox and Intel's Iris graphics control panel? I live in Denmark, so my location is naturally set to Denmark. I do however prefer to run my software in US English.

I've set up Windows 8.1 to use English (Unites States) as the sole language in Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Language. 3rd party programs still default to Danish. It's usually possible to change the language in each program, so this is mostly an annoyance.

Dropbox defaulted to using 'system language', but for some reason this was Danish and not US English. I guess that there is a Registry setting that will fix this language confusion for all the application, so that's what I'm looking for.

This issue is not something new to Windows 8.1. I think it has been here since Windows 95.