# Windows 8 system language persistently wrong

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language

I just did a fresh install of Windows 8. I set my language to English, but with Norwegian keyboard layout, time format, etc...

Every setting I have found that is related to language and region seem to agree with what I did. This is how it looks:

PC Settings:

[image]

Control Panel Language:

[image]

Despite this, some programs still use the wrong language (Norwegian) when the selected language is "System language" or something similar.

One program I have this issue with is Dropbox. I know I can manually change the language on each program, but I want Windows to be 100% English in terms of language. Is there another setting I have missed? Is it based on location? Or is it the program's fault, not Windows?

Edit: I found an almost [identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/892178/how-do-i-change-the-language-for-3rd-party-applications-in-windows?rq=1), but it was unanswered.

Comment: Yes, it’s the programs’ fault. They are not bound to any Windows setting and can do whatever they like.

Comment: The interface of any application is 100% up to the application.  Most will try and respect the language preferences of Windows, but some will not, sounds like Dropbox is one of those that does not.